# The name for this type of static background switching transition with css and html5

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I found this beautiful transition effect but I don't know what is the name for it.

http://agence-belle-epoque.fr/

Basically, the background somehow switch to different image while text seems independent of the background. 
I saw a kind that has overlayed text that flow in front of a seeming static background while scrolling. This one similiar, the only difference is that it switch the whole background.

If I could get the name for this kind of transition and maybe a resource that I can learn from (i.e. tutorial), that will be wonderful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That effect is called Parallax scrolling. There are a bunch of tutorials and libraries to help you achieve it.

Here are some tutorials with different implementations:

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/